# How was this basic differential equation rewritten using algebra?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am in the process of learning differential equations. I found an example I do not understand. I want to know how the differential equation was rewritten to make (a) the subject. I already know the solution, I  only want to understand the missing step.

Where $a$ and $b$ are constants

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = ay - b$$   to $$\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{y - (b/a)}= a$$

Comment: $ay - b = a(y - b/a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = ay - b=a(y-(b/a))\\\frac {\frac{dy}{dt}}{y-(b/a)}=a$$